# process.env doesn't contain ENV VARS when `npm run build` (Ubuntu)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, environment-variables

I'm deploying VueJS project. There is a file that contain API URLs where I use `process.env`. If `API_URL` is defined in production only so I can use `localhost` on my development server and `API_URL` in the production.

```
const apiRoot = process.env.API_URL || 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

export default {
    root: apiRoot,
    auth: {
        jwt: {
            create: urljoin(apiRoot, "auth/jwt/login/"),
            refresh: urljoin(apiRoot, "auth/jwt/refresh/"),
        },
        loginPage: "/login",
        me: urljoin(apiRoot,"users/me/")
    }
}
```

On the server, I've added `EXPORT API_URL='my.api.url'` and then I ran `npm run build`. Then I realized it is still using `127.0.0.1:8000` so I also added the ENV VAR to `/etc/environment` file.

Again, no success. I've rebooted the server.

In cmd line I can do this:

```
echo $API_URL 
'my.api.url'
```

How to make it work? Or how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. Each ENV VAR must start with `VUE_APP_`.

So instead of setting `API_URL`
I need to set `VUE_APP_API_URL`